# What are the differences between two sentences?

Tags: sentence

1. They argued against imports garments.
2. They showed arguments against importing.

Which one is correct? Please, say details about these two sentences.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both are wrong. 1. *imports* should be changed to *importing*. 2. There should be an object after importing unless you are arguing against a total import ban from any country.

Comment: Neither.  You have to argue against something, so you need that something to act like a noun -- "importing garments" or just "imports."  *Show* isn't idiomatic with *arguments*.  You need something like "presented" or "gave."

Answer (score 1):

"They argued against import**ed** garments" is correct.

"They showed (or provided) arguments against importing" is also correct.

The sentences have different meanings. In the first one, they took a position against importing. In the second one, they stated the case against importing, but did not necessarily agree with it.

Comment: Thanks Cliff. But I have a question. deadrat says the second one is wrong. But Cliff said second is correct. I am confused.

Comment: It depends what you mean. Did they say they thought importing was wrong? If so, they argued against importing. Did they explain why importing could be wrong, but did not give their own opinion? Is so, they provided arguments against importing.